Kernel Panic, New Boot Partition, and Grub misconfig?
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I was handed a machine that is failing to restart properly on its own.
Using the Advanced Grub menu, I can boot into 6.5.0-35.generic just fine. It also offers 6.5.0-44-generic, 5.15.0-118-generic, and 5.4.0-173-generic. All of the latter boot into a kernel panic.
Updates were failing and I found /boot to be 100% full (200MB) on /dev/sda1 and I added a new boot partition at /dev/sda4 (1G). Tried to update /etc/fstab, but the UUID from "sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/" is unchanged. I used fdisk to move the bootable flag from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda4 and rebooted. Same behavior, check.
I was now able to run update, upgrade, and dist-upgrade, with a couple of commands to fix missing and such. Autoremove. Autoclean. Update-Grub. All good there. Reboot, same behavior.
I purged the kernels other than 6.5.0-35.generic and 5.15.0-118-generic using "sudo apt-get purge linux-image-#.#.0-#-generic" (autoremove, autoclean, update-grub) Update-Grub finds only 6.5.0-35 and 5.15.0-118. Reboot. Same behavior. What's odd is that the advanced grub menu still offers 6.5.0-35.generic, 6.5.0-44-generic, 5.15.0-118-generic, and 5.4.0-173-generic.
I tried manually removing anything other than 6.5.0-35 and 5.15.0-118 from /boot and /lib/modules.  Autoremove. Autoclean. Update-Grub. Advanced Grub menu still offers 6.5.0-35.generic, 6.5.0-44-generic, 5.15.0-118-generic, and 5.4.0-173-generic.
Is Grub not updating? Still pulling from /dev/sda1 somehow?
ETA: Pics are not showing. Kernel panic says "not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

you are silent on what research you have done but this Stack Exchange Q&A may give you some guidance

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Upgrades can leave old kernels & other obsolete software that then is not in a new dpkg to purge. But grub finds old kernels. Make sure you have good backups & a repair flash drive, so if you accidentally remove all kernels can reinstall one.

Thanks for the links. System also periodically boots to /dev/sda1. When it did, I was able to find the "bad" kernels and purge them. Next boot ran just fine. I found /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda5 have the same UUID. (via sudo blkid /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2). I used "sudo tune2fs -U $(uuidgen) /dev/sda4" to get a new UUID, updated /etc/fstab and grub menu now shows the expected kernels at boot time.
